# SparkSQL on pyspark: how to generate time series?

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, time-series

I'm using SparkSQL on pyspark to store some PostgreSQL tables into DataFrames and then build a query that generates several time series based on a `start` and `stop` columns of type `date`.

Suppose that `my_table` contains:

```
 start      | stop       
-------------------------
 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-05 
 2012-03-20 | 2012-03-23
```

In PostgreSQL it's very easy to do that:

```
SELECT generate_series(start, stop, '1 day'::interval)::date AS dt FROM my_table
```

and it will generate this table:

```
 dt
------------
 2000-01-01
 2000-01-02
 2000-01-03
 2000-01-04
 2000-01-05
 2012-03-20
 2012-03-21
 2012-03-22
 2012-03-23
```

but how to do that using plain SparkSQL? Will it be necessary to use UDFs or some DataFrame methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have dataframe `df` from spark sql, Try this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types as T

def timeseriesDF(start, total):
    series = [start]
    for i xrange( total-1 ):
        series.append(
            F.date_add(series[-1], 1)
        )
    return series

df.withColumn("t_series", F.udf(
                timeseriesDF, 
                T.ArrayType()
            ) ( df.start, F.datediff( df.start, df.stop ) ) 
    ).select(F.explode("t_series")).show()
```

Comment: Thank you, Rakesh. I came up with a less verbose solution, aligned with your idea. I wanted it to be in SparkSQL syntax with as less Python code as possible. I'll accept your answer, but give a look at my solution.

Answer (score 42):

**EDIT**
This creates a dataframe with one row containing an array of consecutive dates:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sequence, to_date, explode, col

spark.sql("SELECT sequence(to_date('2018-01-01'), to_date('2018-03-01'), interval 1 month) as date")

+------------------------------------------+
|                  date                    |
+------------------------------------------+
| ["2018-01-01","2018-02-01","2018-03-01"] |
+------------------------------------------+
```

You can use the [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#explode) function to "pivot" this array into rows:

```
spark.sql("SELECT sequence(to_date('2018-01-01'), to_date('2018-03-01'), interval 1 month) as date").withColumn("date", explode(col("date"))

+------------+
|    date    |
+------------+
| 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-02-01 |
| 2018-03-01 |
+------------+
```

**(End of edit)**

Spark v2.4 support `sequence` function:

> sequence(start, stop, step) - Generates an array of elements from start to stop (inclusive), incrementing by step. The type of the returned elements is the same as the type of argument expressions.
>
> Supported types are: byte, short, integer, long, date, timestamp.
>
> Examples:
>
> SELECT sequence(1, 5);
>
> [1,2,3,4,5]
>
> SELECT sequence(5, 1);
>
> [5,4,3,2,1]
>
> SELECT sequence(to_date('2018-01-01'), to_date('2018-03-01'), interval 1 month);
>
> [2018-01-01,2018-02-01,2018-03-01]

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions.html#sequence

Answer (score 18):

The existing answers will work, but are *very* inefficient. Instead it is better to use `range` and then cast data. In Python

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def generate_series(start, stop, interval):
    """
    :param start  - lower bound, inclusive
    :param stop   - upper bound, exclusive
    :interval int - increment interval in seconds
    """
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    # Determine start and stops in epoch seconds
    start, stop = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(start, stop)], ("start", "stop")
    ).select(
        [col(c).cast("timestamp").cast("long") for c in ("start", "stop")
    ]).first()
    # Create range with increments and cast to timestamp
    return spark.range(start, stop, interval).select(
        col("id").cast("timestamp").alias("value")
    )
```

Example usage:

```py
generate_series("2000-01-01", "2000-01-05", 60 * 60).show(5)  # By hour
```

```
+-------------------+
|              value|
+-------------------+
|2000-01-01 00:00:00|
|2000-01-01 01:00:00|
|2000-01-01 02:00:00|
|2000-01-01 03:00:00|
|2000-01-01 04:00:00|
+-------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

```py
generate_series("2000-01-01", "2000-01-05", 60 * 60 * 24).show()  # By day
```

```
+-------------------+
|              value|
+-------------------+
|2000-01-01 00:00:00|
|2000-01-02 00:00:00|
|2000-01-03 00:00:00|
|2000-01-04 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 15):

@Rakesh answer is correct, but I would like to share a less verbose solution:

```
import datetime
import pyspark.sql.types
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction

# UDF
def generate_date_series(start, stop):
    return [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (stop-start).days + 1)]    

# Register UDF for later usage
spark.udf.register("generate_date_series", generate_date_series, ArrayType(DateType()) )

# mydf is a DataFrame with columns `start` and `stop` of type DateType()
mydf.createOrReplaceTempView("mydf")

spark.sql("SELECT explode(generate_date_series(start, stop)) FROM mydf").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of user10938362 answer, just showing a way to use range without a UDF, provided that you are trying to build a data frame of dates based off of some ingested dataset, rather than with a hardcoded start/stop.

```
# start date is min date
date_min=int(df.agg({'date': 'min'}).first()[0]) 
# end date is current date or alternatively could use max as above
date_max=(
    spark.sql('select unix_timestamp(current_timestamp()) as date_max')
    .collect()[0]['date_max']
    )
# range is int, unix time is s so 60*60*24=day
df=spark.range(date_min, date_max, 60*60*24).select('id')
```