# How to add new rows on date range in dataframe in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe in pyspark as below

```
ID  Name    add date from   date end 
1   aaa yyyyyy  20-01-2018  30-01-2018
2   bbb ffffff  02-11-2018  15-11-2018
```

but looking to get ouput as below

```
ID  Name    add date from   date end 
1   aaa yyyyyy  20-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  21-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  22-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  23-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  24-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  25-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  26-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  27-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  28-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  29-01-2018  30-01-2018
1   aaa yyyyyy  30-01-2018  30-01-2018
2   bbb ffffff  02-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  03-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  04-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  05-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  06-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  07-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  08-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  09-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  10-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  11-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  12-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  13-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  14-11-2018  15-11-2018
2   bbb ffffff  15-11-2018  15-11-2018
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141671/sparksql-on-pyspark-how-to-generate-time-series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```py
a = [(1,'aaa','yyyyyy','20-01-2018','30-01-2018'),
     (2,'bbb','ffffff','02-11-2018','15-11-2018')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(a,["ID","Name","add","date_from","date_end"])

df.show()

+---+----+------+----------+----------+
| ID|Name|   add| date_from|  date_end|
+---+----+------+----------+----------+
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|20-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|02-11-2018|15-11-2018|
+---+----+------+----------+----------+

df.registerTempTable("temp")

result = sqlContext.sql("""
    select t.ID, 
        t.Name, 
        t.add, 
        date_format(date_add(to_date(t.date_from,'dd-MM-yyyy'),pe.i),'dd-MM-yyyy') as date_from, 
        t.date_end 
    from temp t 
    lateral view posexplode(split(space(datediff(to_date(t.date_end,'dd-MM-yyyy'),to_date(t.date_from,'dd-MM-yyyy'))),' ')) pe as i,x
    """)

result.show()

+---+----+------+----------+----------+
| ID|Name|   add| date_from|  date_end|
+---+----+------+----------+----------+
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|20-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|21-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|22-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|23-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|24-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|25-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|26-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|27-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|28-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|29-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  1| aaa|yyyyyy|30-01-2018|30-01-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|02-11-2018|15-11-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|03-11-2018|15-11-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|04-11-2018|15-11-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|05-11-2018|15-11-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|06-11-2018|15-11-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|07-11-2018|15-11-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|08-11-2018|15-11-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|09-11-2018|15-11-2018|
|  2| bbb|ffffff|10-11-2018|15-11-2018|
+---+----+------+----------+----------+
```

[apache-spark](/questions/tagged/apache-spark) [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark) [apache-spark-sql](/questions/tagged/apache-spark-sql)

Answer (score 0):

To perform same in Azure data factory Dataflow, follow below logic.

1. Add a derived column activity in dataflow, This will calculate number of months between start and end date

   ```
   derived_col1=toInteger(round(monthsBetween(end_date,st_date)))
   ```
2. add another derived column activity, this will return array having all the months between 2 dates

   ```
   derived_col2= mapLoop(derived_col1+1,toDate(addMonths(st_date, (toInteger(#index)-1))))
   ```
3. another derived activity, this is similar to explode operation which will return you multiple rows

   ```
   month_column=unfold(derived_col2)
   ```

All this can be fit into 1 derived column activity but just to explain the logic to you, writing in multiple steps