# PySpark: How to generate a dataframe composed of datetime range?

Tags: pyspark

I would like to create a pyspark dataframe composed of a list of datetimes with a specific frequency.

Currently I'm using this approach, which seems quite cumbersome and I'm pretty sure there are better ways

```
# Define date range
START_DATE = dt.datetime(2019,8,15,20,30,0)
END_DATE = dt.datetime(2019,8,16,15,43,0)

# Generate date range with pandas
timerange = pd.date_range(start=START_DATE, end=END_DATE, freq='15min')
# Convert to timestamp
timestamps = [int(x) for x in timerange.values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9]

# Create pyspark dataframe from the above timestamps
(spark.createDataFrame(dates, IntegerType())
    .withColumn('value_date', sf.from_unixtime('value'))
    .drop('value')
    .withColumnRenamed('value_date', 'date').show())
```

which otputs

```
+-------------------+
|               date|
+-------------------+
|2019-08-15 20:30:00|
|2019-08-15 20:45:00|
|2019-08-15 21:00:00|
|2019-08-15 21:15:00|
|2019-08-15 21:30:00|
|2019-08-15 21:45:00|
|2019-08-15 22:00:00|
|2019-08-15 22:15:00|
|2019-08-15 22:30:00|
|2019-08-15 22:45:00|
|2019-08-15 23:00:00|
|2019-08-15 23:15:00|
|2019-08-15 23:30:00|
|2019-08-15 23:45:00|
|2019-08-16 00:00:00|
|2019-08-16 00:15:00|
|2019-08-16 00:30:00|
|2019-08-16 00:45:00|
|2019-08-16 01:00:00|
|2019-08-16 01:15:00|
+-------------------+
```

Can you suggest a smarter way to achieve this?

Thanks

**Edit:**

This seems to work

```
(spark.sql('SELECT sequence({start_date}, {end_date}, 60*15) as timestamp_seq'.format(
    start_date=int(START_DATE.timestamp()), end_date=int(END_DATE.timestamp())
)).withColumn('timestamp', sf.explode('timestamp_seq'))
.select(sf.col('timestamp').cast('timestamp').alias('datetime'))).show()
```

but I'm unable to make it work without the conversion to timestamp.

Comment: By smarter you mean a solution which utilizes the cluster ressources? Have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55199718/6664872) or if you are using spark 2.4 at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57291174/6664872).

Comment: Thanks @cronoik that worked somehow, see the updated question. However I didn't manage to make it with the regular sintax using datetimes without conversion to timestamp. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution working on spark 2.4.3 and python 3.6.8

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.3
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.8 (default, Dec 30 2018 18:50:55)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> def generate_dates(spark,range_list,interval=60*60*24,dt_col="date_time_ref"): # TODO: attention to sparkSession
...     """
...     Create a Spark DataFrame with a single column named dt_col and a range of date within a specified interval (start and stop included).
...     With hourly data, dates end at 23 of stop day
...
...     :param spark: SparkSession or sqlContext depending on environment (server vs local)
...     :param range_list: array of strings formatted as "2018-01-20" or "2018-01-20 00:00:00"
...     :param interval: number of seconds (frequency), output from get_freq()
...     :param dt_col: string with date column name. Date column must be TimestampType
...
...     :returns: df from range
...     """
...     start,stop = range_list
...     temp_df = spark.createDataFrame([(start, stop)], ("start", "stop"))
...     temp_df = temp_df.select([F.col(c).cast("timestamp") for c in ("start", "stop")])
...     temp_df = temp_df.withColumn("stop",F.date_add("stop",1).cast("timestamp"))
...     temp_df = temp_df.select([F.col(c).cast("long") for c in ("start", "stop")])
...     start, stop = temp_df.first()
...     return spark.range(start,stop,interval).select(F.col("id").cast("timestamp").alias(dt_col))
...
>>> date_range = ["2018-01-20 00:00:00","2018-01-23 00:00:00"]
>>> generate_dates(spark,date_range)
DataFrame[date_time_ref: timestamp]
>>> generate_dates(spark,date_range).show()
+-------------------+
|      date_time_ref|
+-------------------+
|2018-01-20 00:00:00|
|2018-01-21 00:00:00|
|2018-01-22 00:00:00|
|2018-01-23 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Sincerely I think your first approach (pd.date_range -> spark.createDataFrame()) is the best approach, since it lets pandas consider eveything related to DST. Simply don't convert in python timestamp objects to `int` but convert them to `str` and then cast column from `StringType` to `TimestampType`.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution just in PySpark using a UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

START_DATE = datetime(2019,8,15,20,30,0)
END_DATE = datetime(2019,8,16,15,43,0)
myTimeDelta = 15 # in min

# Calculate number of interval rows and create DataFrame
timeDiff_min = (END_DATE - START_DATE).total_seconds()/60
N_rows = int(timeDiff_min / myTimeDelta) +1 
df = spark.range(N_rows)

# Create a UDF to calculate the "time" column
@udf(TimestampType())
def calculate_time(id):
    return START_DATE + timedelta(minutes=(id*myTimeDelta))

# Add the "time" column using the UDF
df = (df
      .withColumn("time", calculate_time(df["id"]))
      .drop('id')
)

# Show the resulting DataFrame
df.display()
```

Which outputs:

```
+-------------------+
|               time|
+-------------------+
|2019-08-15 20:30:00|
|2019-08-15 20:45:00|
|2019-08-15 21:00:00|
|2019-08-15 21:15:00|
|2019-08-15 21:30:00|
|2019-08-15 21:45:00|
|2019-08-15 22:00:00|
|2019-08-15 22:15:00|
|2019-08-15 22:30:00|
...
```

Answer (score 0):

And here a version without UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

START_DATE = datetime(2019,8,15,20,30,0)
END_DATE = datetime(2019,8,16,15,43,0)
myTimeDelta = 15 # in min

# Calculate number of interval rows and create DataFrame
timeDiff_min = (END_DATE - START_DATE).total_seconds()/60
N_rows = int(timeDiff_min / myTimeDelta) +1 
df = spark.range(N_rows)

# Add time column to dataframe
df = df.withColumn('time', lit(START_DATE + df.id * timedelta(minutes=myTimeDelta)))

# Show the resulting DataFrame
df.display()
```