# How to generate date values into a dataframe in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

May I know what's wrong with below code? it does not print anything.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date, current_timestamp,last_day,next_day, date_format, date_add, year, month, dayofmonth, dayofyear, dayofweek, date_trunc, date_sub, to_date, add_months, weekofyear, quarter, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType, IntegerType
ss = SparkSession.builder.appName('DateDim').master('local[1]').getOrCreate()
df = ss.createDataFrame([],StructType([]))
current_date()
df = df.select(current_date().alias("current_date"),next_day(current_date(), 'sunday').alias("next_day"),dayofweek(current_date()).alias("day_of_week"),dayofmonth(current_date()).alias("day_of_month"),dayofyear(current_date()).alias("day_of_year"),last_day(current_date()).alias("last_day"),year(current_date()).alias("year"),month(current_date()).alias("month"), weekofyear(current_date()).alias("week_of_year"),quarter(current_date()).alias("quarter")).collect()
print(df)
for i in range(1, 1000):
    print(i)
for i in range(1, 1000):
    v_date = date_add(v_date, i)
    df.unionAll(df.select(v_date.alias("current_date"),next_day(v_date,'sunday').alias("next_day"),dayofweek(v_date).alias("day_of_week"),dayofmonth(v_date).alias("day_of_month"),dayofyear(v_date).alias("day_of_year"),last_day(v_date).alias("last_day"),year(v_date).alias("year"),month(v_date).alias("month"), weekofyear(v_date).alias("week_of_year"),quarter(v_date).alias("quarter")))
df.show()
```

Comment: it's because there are no rows in the initial `df`. creating new columns will only create columns with no values as there are no rows in the `df` being used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SparkSQL on pyspark: how to generate time series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141671/sparksql-on-pyspark-how-to-generate-time-series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting zero rows because there are no rows in the initial `df`. Any columns being created will have no values as there are no rows in `df`.

It seems you're trying to create a dataframe with 1000 dates starting from the current day. There's a simple approach using `sequence` function.

```py
data_sdf = spark.createDataFrame([(1,)], 'id string')

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('min_dt', func.current_date().cast('date')). \
    withColumn('max_dt', func.date_add('min_dt', 1000).cast('date')). \
    withColumn('all_dates', func.expr('sequence(min_dt, max_dt, interval 1 day)')). \
    withColumn('dates_exp', func.explode('all_dates')). \
    drop('id'). \
    show(10)

# +----------+----------+--------------------+----------+
# |    min_dt|    max_dt|           all_dates| dates_exp|
# +----------+----------+--------------------+----------+
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-08-27|
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-08-28|
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-08-29|
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-08-30|
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-08-31|
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-09-01|
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-09-02|
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-09-03|
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-09-04|
# |2022-08-27|2025-05-23|[2022-08-27, 2022...|2022-09-05|
# +----------+----------+--------------------+----------+
# only showing top 10 rows
```

`select` the `dates_exp` field for further use.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `range()` function which generates rows (using `sequence` you will generate an array which you then need to `explode` into rows).

That's how you can use it:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, next_day, dayofweek, dayofmonth, dayofyear, last_day, year, month, \
    weekofyear, quarter, current_date

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

(
    spark
    .range(0, 1000)
    .alias("id")
    .select(
        (current_date() + col('id').cast("int")).alias("date")
    )
    .select(
        "date",
        next_day("date", 'sunday').alias("next_sunday"),
        dayofweek("date").alias("day_of_week"),
        dayofmonth("date").alias("day_of_month"),
        dayofyear("date").alias("day_of_year"),
        last_day("date").alias("last_day"),
        year("date").alias("year"),
        month("date").alias("month"),
        weekofyear("date").alias("week_of_year"),
        quarter("date").alias("quarter")
    )
).show()
```

it returns

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+----+-----+------------+-------+
|      date|next_sunday|day_of_week|day_of_month|day_of_year|  last_day|year|month|week_of_year|quarter|
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+----+-----+------------+-------+
|2022-09-22| 2022-09-25|          5|          22|        265|2022-09-30|2022|    9|          38|      3|
|2022-09-23| 2022-09-25|          6|          23|        266|2022-09-30|2022|    9|          38|      3|
|2022-09-24| 2022-09-25|          7|          24|        267|2022-09-30|2022|    9|          38|      3|
|2022-09-25| 2022-10-02|          1|          25|        268|2022-09-30|2022|    9|          38|      3|
|2022-09-26| 2022-10-02|          2|          26|        269|2022-09-30|2022|    9|          39|      3|
|2022-09-27| 2022-10-02|          3|          27|        270|2022-09-30|2022|    9|          39|      3|
|2022-09-28| 2022-10-02|          4|          28|        271|2022-09-30|2022|    9|          39|      3|
|2022-09-29| 2022-10-02|          5|          29|        272|2022-09-30|2022|    9|          39|      3|
|2022-09-30| 2022-10-02|          6|          30|        273|2022-09-30|2022|    9|          39|      3|
|2022-10-01| 2022-10-02|          7|           1|        274|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          39|      4|
|2022-10-02| 2022-10-09|          1|           2|        275|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          39|      4|
|2022-10-03| 2022-10-09|          2|           3|        276|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          40|      4|
|2022-10-04| 2022-10-09|          3|           4|        277|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          40|      4|
|2022-10-05| 2022-10-09|          4|           5|        278|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          40|      4|
|2022-10-06| 2022-10-09|          5|           6|        279|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          40|      4|
|2022-10-07| 2022-10-09|          6|           7|        280|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          40|      4|
|2022-10-08| 2022-10-09|          7|           8|        281|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          40|      4|
|2022-10-09| 2022-10-16|          1|           9|        282|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          40|      4|
|2022-10-10| 2022-10-16|          2|          10|        283|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          41|      4|
|2022-10-11| 2022-10-16|          3|          11|        284|2022-10-31|2022|   10|          41|      4|
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+----+-----+------------+-------+
only showing top 20 rows
```