# PySpark: How to create DataFrame containing date range

Tags: python, dataframe, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a PySpark data frame with a single column that contains the date range, but I keep getting this error. I also tried converting it to an int, but I am not sure if you are even supposed to do that.

```
# Gets an existing SparkSession or, if there is no existing one, creates a new one
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pyspark-shellTest2').getOrCreate()

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date, asc
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
import datetime

# Start and end dates for the date range
start_date = "2022-08-20"
end_date = "2022-10-03"


# Create a DataFrame with a single column containing the date range
date_range_df = spark.range(start_date, end_date) \
                     .withColumn("date", to_date(col("id")))
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: try this  [time series in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141671/sparksql-on-pyspark-how-to-generate-time-series), and let us know if this works!

Comment: the [`range`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.range.html#pyspark-sql-sparksession-range) you're using accepts integers only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `sequence` sql function to create an array of dates using the start and end. this array can be exploded to get new rows.

see example below

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(start_date, end_date)]). \
    toDF(['start', 'end']). \
    withColumn('start', func.to_date('start')). \
    withColumn('end', func.to_date('end')). \
    withColumn('date_seq', func.expr('sequence(start, end, interval 1 day)')). \
    select(func.explode('date_seq').alias('date')). \
    show(10)

# +----------+
# |      date|
# +----------+
# |2022-08-20|
# |2022-08-21|
# |2022-08-22|
# |2022-08-23|
# |2022-08-24|
# |2022-08-25|
# |2022-08-26|
# |2022-08-27|
# |2022-08-28|
# |2022-08-29|
# +----------+
# only showing top 10 rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run it  gives a `TypeError: col should be Column` . Do I have to use `lit`?

Comment: @Aztec619 - what did you actually execute? it doesn't throw an error in my run.

Comment: I actually was able to fix it. Thanks for the help!